# Detecting Top / Global Navigation Settings Programmatically

Tags: navigation, top-link-bar, managed-navigation

If a publishing site collection has managed or structural navigation set as the source for the top navigation, how do you work with these settings programmatically? The [`SPWeb.Navigation.TopNavigationBar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.navigation.spnavigation.topnavigationbar.aspx) property returns an entirely different set of navigation nodes (the Top Link Bar on non-publishing sites).

Here are some UI screenshots where the settings I'm talking about are located:

Not-Publishing (Top Link Bar Settings):

[image: Top Link Bar Settings]

Publishing (Global Navigation Settings):

[image: Publishing Navigation Settings]
[image: Global Navigation Settings]

How can you programmatically detect whether a site is using the `SPNavigation.TopNavigationBar`, Managed Navigation, or Structural Navigation for its Global Navigation / top navigation settings?

Comment: Reverse compiling the Microsoft.SharePoint.Publish.dll now... will add an answer if I can get this working. Otherwise, maybe someone else already has a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, so after peering into the inner workings of the code behind for those settings pages, I've found that you can detect the source of the publishing site's navigation by using the [`WebNavigationSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.navigation.webnavigationsettings.aspx) class and reading its [`GlobalNavigation.Source`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.navigation.standardnavigationsettings.source.aspx) property (a [`StandardNavigationSource` enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.navigation.standardnavigationsource.aspx)) like such:

```
if (PublishingWeb.IsPublishingWeb(web))
{
    WebNavigationSettings settings = new WebNavigationSettings(web);
    switch (settings.GlobalNavigation.Source)
    {
        case StandardNavigationSource.PortalProvider:
            // Data source is Structured Navigation
            break;
        case StandardNavigationSource.TaxonomyProvider:
            // Data source is Managed Navigation
            break;
        case StandardNavigationSource.InheritFromParentWeb:
            // Root navigation data source is inherited
            break;
        case StandardNavigationSource.Unknown:
            // The documentation for this value states:
            // "Returns a value of unknown to indicate an advanced configuration
            // that does not correspond to one of the standard configurations.
            // This value cannot be manually assigned to the Source property."
            break;
    }
}
else
{
    // Non-publishing site, root source is SPNavigation.TopNavigationBar
}
```